# How to use schema aware XSLT processor in Mule 3.3 application

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, mule

I intent to validate input xml and output xml from my xsl stylesheet. I am following this [developerworks post](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-schemaxslt/index.html#iratings) to do that.

When I try to run my application through `Mule Server`, it fails with following exception

```
Error at xsl:import-schema on line 8 of :
  XTSE1650: To use xsl:import-schema, you need the schema-aware version of Saxon from
  http://www.saxonica.com/
Error at Product on line 23 of :
  XTSE1660: To perform validation, a schema-aware XSLT processor is needed
Error on line 23 of :
  XTTE1512: There is no global element declaration for Product, so strict validation will fail
```

1. Is it possible to do in Mule?
2. Is this an efficient way for schema validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [XML module for Mule offers a validation filter](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/XML+Module+Reference#XMLModuleReference-Filters):

```
<mule-xml:schema-validation-filter
    schemaLocations="com/myapp/schemas/schema.xsd, com/myapp/schemas/anotherSchema.xsd"/>
```

I suggest you try first using it and see if it fits your needs.

Otherwise, if you stick with your current approach, you'll probably have to replace the Saxon JARs Mule embeds with the schema-aware version, or ship the schema-aware version in your application /libs and use class-loader filtering to ensure the right version is used.

Comment: David, just to clarify to make sure am not missing anything, as I need  to validate both input and output xml, are you suggesting to put <mule-xml> processor before and after the xsl transformer? Can you comment on performance of each of these approaches.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm suggesting. And no, I can't comment on the performance as I've never done this kind of pre/post transformation validation. At the end of the day, the bottleneck will be the XSL-T transformer as it is a pooled transformer in Mule.

Comment: David, I'm trying to use this xml schema validation filter as child of `<choice><when>` element and gets `CheckExclusiveAttributesAndChildren$CheckExclusiveAttributesAndChildrenException`. More detailed exception is [here](http://pastebin.com/uqFF3Vzu)

Comment: If it starts with a filter, you need to wrap the content of the `<when>` element with a `<processor-chain>`.